# knockout js checkbox filter using visible

Tags: knockout.js

i am using knockout js to create a simple checkbox filter but i am now at a point where i could do with some help see below.
VIEW

```
<table style="float: left;margin-right: 200px;">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: plants">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: plant"></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: is_checked, value: plant, event: { change: $root.filterJobs }"></td>    
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: jobs">
    <tr data-bind="visible: visible">
        <td data-bind="text: plant"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: tested"></td>  
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

MODEL

```
  function viewModel() {

  var root = this;
  root.plants = ko.observableArray([{'plant' : '1-1', 'is_checked': true}, {'plant' : '1-2', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-3', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-4', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-5', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-6', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-7', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-8', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-9', 'is_checked': true}]);

  root.jobs = ko.observableArray([{'plant' : '1-1', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-1', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-2', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-2', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-3', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-3', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-4', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-4', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-5', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-5', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-6', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-6', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-7', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-7', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-8', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-8', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-9', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-9', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true}]);

  root.filterJobs = function() {
    var self = this;    
    var plant = self.plant;
    var is_checked =  self.is_checked;
    console.log(plant, is_checked);

    if(is_checked){
        //how do i pass the plant the plant and visible(true) to the jobs loop
        root.jobs.visible(true)
    }
    else {
        //how do i pass the plant the plant and visible(false) to the jobs loop
        root.jobs.visible(false);
    }
  }
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

i need to update the jobs loop so that visible is false or true depending if the checkbox is checked or not where the plant in the plants loop is the same as the plant in the jobs loop the conole.log is passing the plant value and true / false if checkbox is checked

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your viewModel code, I think it working fine.

```
  function viewModel() {

  var root = this;
  root.plants = ko.observableArray([{'plant' : '1-1', 'is_checked': true}, {'plant' : '1-2', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-3', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-4', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-5', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-6', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-7', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-8', 'is_checked': true},{'plant' : '1-9', 'is_checked': true}]);

  root.jobs = ko.observableArray([{'plant' : '1-1', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-1', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-2', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-2', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-3', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-3', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-4', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-4', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-5', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-5', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-6', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-6', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-7', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-7', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-8', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-8', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-9', 'tested' : 'Wednesday', 'visible' : true},{'plant' : '1-9', 'tested' : 'Monday', 'visible' : true}]);

  root.filterJobs = function() {
    var self = this;    
    var plant = self.plant;
    var is_checked =  self.is_checked;
    console.log(plant, is_checked);

                   if (root.jobs !== undefined) {
                       return ko.utils.arrayFilter(root.jobs, function (item) {
                           if (item.visible) {
                               return true;
                           }
                           else {
                              return false;
                           }
                       });
                   }

  }
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```